# stat_compare_means label overlapping

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, boxplot

I'm trying to use ggboxplot() and stat_compare_means() to add a label to a boxplot, but when I choose wilcox.test in stat_compare_means(), the label is overlapping in the plot, I tried to use the label.x and label.y to adjust the position of the label, but it didn't work. The code and plots are shown below. Thank you so much for anyone who helps.

```
CNTN2_comparisons = list(c('Esophagus Normal Tissue', 'Esophagus Primary Tumor'), 
                         c('Prostate Normal Tissue', 'Prostate Primary Tumor'), 
                         c("Skin Primary Tumor", "Skin Normal Tissue"), 
                         c("Skin Metastatic", "Skin Normal Tissue"), 
                         c("Skin Metastatic", "Skin Primary Tumor"), 
                         c('Testis Normal Tissue', 'Testis Primary Tumor'))

ggboxplot(protein_list,x = "Group", y= "log2(TPM_CNTN2+1)", 
+           color="Group", palette=c('#91D1C2FF', "#F39B7FFF", 
+                     '#91D1C2FF', "#F39B7FFF", 
+                     '#91D1C2FF', "#E64B35FF", "#F39B7FFF", 
+                     '#91D1C2FF', "#F39B7FFF"), 
+           width = 0.4, size = 1) + 
+   stat_compare_means(comparisons = CNTN2_comparisons, method = 'wilcox.test') + 
+   stat_compare_means(method = 'wilcox.test')
[1] FALSE
> head(protein_list)
# A tibble: 6 × 9
  TCGA_GTEX_main_category sample                   Group                   TPM_CNTN2 LY6G6C XPNPEP2  PRSS8 Gene_CNTN2 `log2(TPM_CNTN2+1)`
  <chr>                   <chr>                    <fct>                       <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>                    <dbl>
1 GTEX Esophagus          GTEX-13NYB-0926-SM-5IFFA Esophagus Normal Tissue      26.9 1218.     81.7 23657. CNTN2                     4.80
2 GTEX Esophagus          GTEX-13FLV-1126-SM-5J2NO Esophagus Normal Tissue      43.2  731.    175.  13970. CNTN2                     5.47
3 GTEX Esophagus          GTEX-11DXY-1426-SM-5N9CN Esophagus Normal Tissue      38.5  984.    117.  28725. CNTN2                     5.30
4 GTEX Esophagus          GTEX-12KS4-0926-SM-5BC5S Esophagus Normal Tissue      68.6   93.4   142.   3191. CNTN2                     6.12
5 GTEX Esophagus          GTEX-WHSE-1526-SM-4M1XH  Esophagus Normal Tissue      21.6  262.     62.7  7132. CNTN2                     4.50
6 GTEX Esophagus          GTEX-12ZZX-1326-SM-5DUWI Esophagus Normal Tissue      50.3 2592.    159.   5518. CNTN2                     5.68
```

[image]

I tried to use label.x and label.y to adjust the position of the label, but it didn't work.

```
ggboxplot(protein_list,x = "Group", y= "log2(TPM_CNTN2+1)", 
          color="Group", palette=c('#91D1C2FF', "#F39B7FFF", 
                    '#91D1C2FF', "#F39B7FFF", 
                    '#91D1C2FF', "#E64B35FF", "#F39B7FFF", 
                    '#91D1C2FF', "#F39B7FFF"), 
          width = 0.4, size = 1) + 
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = CNTN2_comparisons, method = 'wilcox.test') + 
  stat_compare_means(method = 'wilcox.test',label.y = c(12, 12, 12, 12, 12), label.x = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5))
```

[image]

I want to add only one label to the plot without overlapping.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, I have added the compare information.